# Does adding flour before egg coating and breadcrumbs help sticking?

Tags: deep-frying

When deep frying chicken, assuming:

flour and seasonings
egg and milk mix
breadcrumbs

does the first layer of flour help the egg to stick better? Why not just add seasonings to the breadcrumbs and skip the flour layer entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is helpful for an initial dip in flour...as it would  help the egg to stick better...
A little addition of oil in the egg also helps thin the liquid coating,  with the extra fat from the egg will help brown the breadcrumbs better underneath. The proteins in the flour and eggs help the bread crumbs stick to the food once cooked. A fabulous and crunchy crust is formed around the food once fried in a pan.
 Do let me know if my answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

The first coat of flour gives the egg something to adhere to, and creates a kind of paste for the breadcrumbs to adhere to. Breadcrumbs stick to this paste far better than egg alone.

Comment: Is there a difference between applying the flour and egg separately and combining them before dipping?

Comment: I imagine combining them would form a batter. Batters tend to puff out when dropped in oil (at least when deep frying), which steams the food inside. Think of how fried fish works. I imagine there would be textural differences.